# Simplifying LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
public List<KeyValuePair<decimal, string>> getDepartments()
{
    using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities ())
    {
        var dept = (from i in db.Departments
                    orderby i.DepartmentName
                    select new
                    {
                        i.Id,
                        i.DepartmentName
                    }).ToDictionary(Key => Key.Id, Value => Value.DepartmentName);

        return dept.ToList<KeyValuePair<decimal, string>>();
    }
}
```

In the above function, I need a `List<KeyValuePair<decimal, string>>`. So I first convert IQueryable to Dictionary `.ToDictionary(Key => Key.Id, Value => Value.DepartmentName)` and then to List using `.ToList<KeyValuePair<decimal, string>>();`.

But it seems expensive. How do I reduce it? How do I avoid using too much conversions(like ToDictionary, ToList)?

**UPDATE 1:**

It was someone else's code, just figured why that `.ToList` is there after checking the response data in Chrome. When `.ToList` is used, the response data would look like `0: {Key:13, Value:Marketing} 1: {Key:5, Value:Research}` which populates a dropdown and is angularjs-friendly. When I remove it and return it as a `Dictionary` the response data would look like `{"13":"Marketing","5":"Research"}` which fails to populate the dropdown. So I can't remove `.ToList`. Is there a way I can get a `List<KeyValuePair<decimal, string>>` from `IQueryable` without using `ToDictionary`?

Comment: Why do you need a `List<KeyValuePair<decimal, string>>`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel this method is in a WebAPI project, it returns a List<KeyValuePair<decimal, string>> to angularjs's $http which I'll use to load a dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the first call (todictionary on iqueryable) is going to be expensive (database call), the 2nd one is done in memory and unless you're working on a huge huge dataset, it's gonna be pretty much free.

However i can't think of any reason "why" you'd want to convert from a dictionary to a list of keyvaluepairs since a dictionary is already an ienumerable of those keyvaluepairs.

So no it's not expensive but you're probably better of reworking the consuming code and just returning the dictionnary.

update after your comment : Try this and see if it shows the json you want :

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<decimal, string>> getDepartments()
{
    using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities ())
    {
        var dept = (from i in db.Departments
                    orderby i.DepartmentName
                    select new
                    {
                        i.Id,
                        i.DepartmentName
                    }).ToDictionary(Key => Key.Id, Value => Value.DepartmentName);
        foreach(var item in dept)
           yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn! I forgot that Dictionary is also an `IEnumerable`. Ty. :)

Comment: It was someone else's code, just figured why that `.ToList` is there after checking the response data in Chrome. When `.ToList` is used, the response data would look like `0: {Key:13, Value:Marketing}
1: {Key:5, Value:Research}` which populates a dropdown and is angularjs-friendly. When I remove it and return it as a `Dictionary` the response data would look like `{"13":"Marketing","5":"Research"}` which fails to populate the dropdown. So I can't remove `.ToList`. Is there a way I can get a `List<KeyValuePair<decimal, string>>` from `IQueryable` without using `ToDictionary`?

Comment: Once again you need to show the consuming code (the code that is calling this), i'm betting that you're having a special case treatment for dictionaries. You need to stop focusing on the todictionary, it's not costly so there is no issue (you'll notice no perf loss by using it or not pretty much in your case) however it's probably possible to remove the additional tolist, i'm about to paste another code block, give it a try and see if you get the proper JSON you want out of it.